# Rspec fails on "let"s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a mailer

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send1(a, b, c)
    #.....
    mail(....).deliver
  end

  def send2(a, b, c)
    #.....
    mail(....).deliver
  end
end
```

And I test it

```
describe MyMailer do
  describe "#send1" do
    let(:a) { "a@b.com" }
    let(:b) { "message" }
    let(:c) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
    let(:send1_email1) { MyMailer.send1 a, b, c }

    after(:all) { MyMailer.deliveries.clear }

    it "should send an email" do
      expect(MyMailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
    end

    #........ other ITs testing send1_emai1

  describe "#send2" do
    let(:d) { "aaa@bbbb.com" }
    let(:e) { FactoryGirl.create :admin }
    let(:g) { "message2" }
    let(:send1_emai2) { MyMailer.send2 d, e, g }

    after(:all) { MyMailer.deliveries.clear }

    it "should send an email2" do
      expect(MyMailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
    end

    #........ other ITs testing send1_emai2

end
```

So most of the time it fails due to the errors should send an email expect 1 got 2 and should send an email expect 1 got 4 or 0
Sometimes the numbers are different (got 0 - 4). I tried to do this:

```
  let!(:send1_email) { MyMailer.send1 a, b, c }
  let!(:send1_emai2) { MyMailer.send2 d, e, g }
```

But it also failed.

```
Failure/Error: expect(MyMailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)

       expected: 1
            got: 4
```

I wonder why?

Previously I used `before :all` and `@variables` and everything was well (no errors)

**The same errors:**

```
   it "should send an email" do
      expect(MyMailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
      MyMailer.deliveries.clear
    end

   it "should send an email2" do
     expect(MyMailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
     MyMailer.deliveries.clear
   end
```

Comment: Please post actual backtraces and errors.

Comment: @TanelSuurhans, here you go. As I said, "got" differs sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation states at [this location](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let).

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.

Also i'm sure you are aware that rspec runs examples in random order, meaning other examples call the mail-sending let() helper, meaning by the time it gets to your test, the suite has already sent out 4 emails, making your test fail. You should not rely on the order of defining tests. You should be making sure that your test data is scrubbed and cleaned before your examples.

Comment: I would say you need to clear your deliveries after each send/before each test that relies on it.

Comment: only the two first ones rely on it and they fail.

Comment: As I noted earlier - the first test you write is not the first one ran. Your examples are ran in random order, so the test you wrote first might easily be the last on being ran, meaning other tests have send multiple emails already.

Comment: after all, so what if the first one will run after the second one? I call `let(:send1_email1) { MyMailer.send1 a, b, c }` only one time for each `describe` and check `MyMailer.deliveries.count` also one time. And I clear `MyMailer.deliveries.clear ` in each describe.

Comment: `the suite has already sent out 4 emails, making your test fail` - that's not possible because they are called exactly 2 times thought the tests - in the first `let` and in the second one and nowhere else.

Comment: @Alexander: let stores the block to run later, as a _delayed_ computation. (This is similar to putting your code in a loop. This is why Tanel said that Rspec sends a mail for every example, not just the 2 you were looking at.) So the mistake was to use `let` in place of `before :all`.  Instead you should either send the mail _inside_ the relevant examples, or go back to using what worked for you, `before :all`.  Whatever you do, your code will be easier to read if you use `after :each` or `before :each` to clear the deliveries.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between `let` and `let!`

`let` is instantiated only when called, in other words, rspec won't be looking inside `let` block before you use the variable.

```
let(:send1_email2) { MyMailer.send2 d, e, g }
it 'testing' do
  # email not sent yet because we use let without bang
  expect(MyMailer.deliveries.count).to eq(0)

  send1_email2.call_a_method
  # now email is sent since we used the variable send1_email2
  expect(MyMailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
end
```

`let!` is instantiated as if it was a `before` block

```
let!(:send1_email2) { MyMailer.send2 d, e, g }
it 'testing' do
  # before we do anything the email is sent because we used let with a bang
  expect(MyMailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
end
```

Additionaly do no user `after(:all) { MyMailer.deliveries.clear }`, but `after { MyMailer.deliveries.clear }` instead, otherwise your counter won't be cleared between your examples

Comment: what's the difference between after :all and after? after means after :each?